# Calculus of variations integral with additional condition

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, calculus-of-variations

Find the functions $y_1$ and $y_2$ with which the functional $$J = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}(2y_1y_2 + (y_1^{'})^2+(y_2{'})^2)dx$$ has conditional extremum.
$$\begin{cases}y_1(0)=-1,\\y_2(0)=1,&\end{cases}\quad\quad\begin{cases}y_1(\pi/2)=\frac{\pi^2}4-1,\\y_2(\pi/2)=\frac{\pi^2}4+1.&\end{cases}$$
With additional condition $y_1^{\prime}+y_2^{\prime}=4x.$

Here are my ideas or hints I've been given so far:

It is a conditional functional problem (due to additional condition). We need to set up a "helping" functional such $J^{*}=\int_{a}^{b}(F+\lambda(x)g)dx$ and solve using Lagrange multipliers. Then, I am not sure I know how to proceed further. The answer should look like $y_1=$ and $y_2=$, without constants because to find them we are given the boundary conditions. I would appreciate if someone could show how to solve this problem.

Here is my work so far:

$J^{*}=\int_{a}^{b}((F+\lambda(x)g)dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(2y_1y_2+ (y_1^{'})^2+(y_2{'})^2)+\lambda (y'_1+y_2^{'}))  dx $

Now I was suggested to set some system of equations, but I don't know what they mean by that.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the method. But the idea behind this problem was to practice using Lagrange multipliers I am barely familiar with. That's why I posted it here.

Comment: @Gonçalo I assumed it would be clear based on including $J^{*}=\int_{a}^{b}(F+\lambda(x)g)dx$?

Comment: Are you saying $\lambda$ doesn't mean Lagrange multipliers here? Is there something I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

You missed a term in $J^{*}$; it should be $J^{*}=\int_0^{\pi/2}F^{*}(x,y_1,y_2,y_1',y_2',\lambda)\,dx$, where
$$
F^{*}(x,y_1,y_2,y_1',y_2',\lambda)=2y_1y_2+(y_1')^2+(y_2')^2+\lambda(y_1'+y_2'-4x). \tag{1}
$$
Now, write the Euler-Lagrange equations for $F^{*}$:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial F^{*}}{\partial y_1}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F^{*}}{\partial y_1'}\right)=0\implies 2y_2-2y_1''-\lambda'=0, \tag{2a} \\
&\frac{\partial F^{*}}{\partial y_2}-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F^{*}}{\partial y_2'}\right)=0\implies 2y_1-2y_2''-\lambda'=0, \tag{2b} \\
&\frac{\partial F^{*}}{\partial \lambda}=0\implies y_1'+y_2'-4x = 0. \tag{2c}
\end{align}
Can you continue from here?

Comment: I tried subtracting the the $(2a)$ and $(2b)$ equations to get rid of $\lambda$ and group like terms. I got $2(y_2-y1)+2(y_2^{''}-y_1^{''})=0$, it should simplify at this point using the conditions I've been given, but  don't see it.

Comment: Let $z= y_2-y_1$. Then the equation you got can be rewritten as $z''+z=0$. Now find the solution to this equation subject to the boundary conditions $z(0)= y_2(0)-y_1(0)=2$ and $z(\pi/2)=y_2(\pi/2)-y_1(\pi/2)=2$.

Comment: Yes, I have got this, but how do I get the expression for $y_1$ and $y_2$ from this? Maybe I just don't see it for some reason.

Comment: Now solve Eq. $(2c)$.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. Have I made any errors here though? The particular solution for $z$ is $z(x) = 2 \cos x + 2 \sin x.$
Now, using the relationship $y_1 = y_2 - z$ and the condition $y_1' + y_2' = 4x$:
1. $y_1' + y_2' = (z + y_1') + y_2' = 4x.$
2. $z' + y_1' + y_2' = 4x.$
3. $z' + 4x = 4x.$

Integrating the last equation gives $z = 2x^2.$ The final expressions for $y_1$ and $y_2$ are:

$y_1 = 2\cos x + 2\sin x - 2x^2.$ and
$y_2 = 2x^2 + 2\cos x + 2\sin x.$

Comment: $y_1'+y_2'=4x$ and $y_1(0)+y_2(0)=0$ imply $y_1+y_2=2x^2$. Combining this result with $y_2-y_1=2\cos x + 2\sin x$, we find $y_1=x^2-\cos x-\sin x$ and $y_2=x^2+\cos x+\sin x.$

Comment: I now see where I did my errors, thank you.